# Java configuration for SAAJInInterceptor and WSS4JInInterceptor beans

Tags: spring-boot, cxf, ws-security

I have a web application that provides a soap web service using apache cxf and spring boot. So I have no xml file in my classpath to configure my beans, they are all configured in java configuration.I would like to set up authentication with ws-security from cxf.
So I would like to know if there are java configurations for the SAAJInInterceptor and WSS4JInInterceptor beans for example like this:

> ```
> @Bean
> public ServletRegistrationBean cxfServlet() {
>     ServletRegistrationBean servlet = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/services/*");
>     servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
>     return servlet;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add the interceptor when you create your endpoint :

```
Map<String,Object> interceptorConfig = new HashMap<String,Object>();
// set the properties of you WSS4J config
// ...
WSS4JInInterceptor myInterceptor = new WSS4JInInterceptor(interceptorConfig);
myEndpoint.getInInterceptors().add(myInterceptor);
```

Another solution is by using annotation with `@InInterceptors`

Comment: Thank's for your prompt reaction ... how I can do it to use the @InInterceptors annotation?